# Do I need to buy data packs to be competitive?

Tags: deck-building, android-netrunner, tournament

I've seen that there are tournaments of Android: Netrunner.

Regarding data packs, is it necessary to buy all the data packs to have a chance to win those tournaments?

I guess the cards allowed to be played in tournaments are described to players before the tournaments and the constructed decks have to stick to the tournaments rules...

If I stick to the core set of cards, do I have a chance of winning a game against someone who has all the expansions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In theory, all Android: Netrunner cards are fairly well balanced, and the core set provides a good broad base for building decks, but in practice **I think buying data packs is necessary to remain competitive**.

You will probably find that you will struggle against a player of similar ability even in a casual environment if they have all data packs and you have none. Competitive tournament players will have two (or commonly three) core sets and every data pack.

Having said that, **you don't need to buy *every* data pack**. A little research into what kind of deck you'd like to build (possibly using proxies) will allow you to pinpoint data packs containing cards that will help your deck in particular.

One final comment worthy of note: how you play with your deck is often more important than how you build your deck. A good player with a bad deck will often overcome a bad player with a good deck.

Comment: @AndyM No problem. Welcome to the site!